# SQL Server : excluding rows from a table IF there is another row with the same col value and a particular secondary column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table with columns for `Account` and `InvoiceID`, an account can have multiple `InvoiceID` rows and I'm trying to add an option that will filter out ALL account rows if there is a row that has a particular `Status`.

For my small data set I might have 15 records, 3 accounts each having 5 invoices. If one of those records has a `Status` of `0` I would like that and the remaining 4 to be filtered out. I tried using `EXCEPT` to do this but it only filtered out the single row with the value of 0 and left the remainders.

I've only worked with the basics of SQL Server before so I'm feeling quite lost looking at all the more advanced features you can use in a statement so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Edit for example data:

```
Id  Account  enddate     Status  InvoiceID
0   5000     2011-10-10  1       1
1   5000     2012-10-10  1       2
2   5000     2013-10-10  1       3
3   5000     2014-10-10  1       4
4   5000     2015-10-10  0       5
5   5999     2013-10-10  1       1
6   5999     2014-10-10  1       2
7   5999     2015-10-10  1       3
8   1002     2014-10-10  1       1
9   1002     2015-10-10  1       2
```

If I run a query for invoices that end in october and come back with these results, I want to further filter out ALL records of Account 5000 because it has a row with a status of 0 and leave the records for accounts 5999 and 1002.

Comment: Sample data and expected output?

Comment: "if there is a row that has a particular Status", Where does status come from? Is it a column? Is it in the Account or Invoice Table? What data type is it?

Comment: @SteveJ I added some sample data that should clear that up

Comment: @ZoffDino I've added some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `not exists` clause, to filter out any rows that have the same account number as a row with status 0. Something along the lines of the following:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where not exists (
  select account
  from table1 t2
  where t2.account=t1.account
    and t2.status=0
)
```

A slightly different approach would be:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where account not in (
  select distinct account
  from table1 t2
  where t2.status=0 )
```

Comment: I'm just using one table but I think that's done it, thank you.

Comment: Bryan, your pastebin query has `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Renewal WHERE Renewal.Status = 0) ` which doesn't link back to the original account, so the not exists in that case will mean no rows fulfil the condition. I can't see your data, but you can probably use both the inner join and then in the not exists, use `where renewal.status=0 and renewal.account=customers.account`. The two clauses do different things, one is bringing in new renewals columns, the other is limiting to rows where a renewals.status=0 is present for the account.

Comment: Thanks @wwkudu, I deleted that question after I realized I wasn't applying the same where clauses to the  WHERE NOT EXISTS query and so it was applying it to the entire record set and not just my 3 month window